# The key is invalid JQuery syntax because it is missing a closing bracket because of summernote Html Editor

Tags: jquery, summernote

I have added an `Html Editor` to my website using summernote plugin. Before that, my form has been posted and all things work fine but after the implement of `Html Editor,` it gives an error.

I have just add the `summernote.js` and `summernote.css` and just write below line:

```
$('.summernote').summernote();
```

[image]

Am I missing some configuration or any other issue I don't understand?
Is there any way to resolve this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Could we have the stack trace?

Comment: If you use Bootstrap, you need Summernote for BS.
Download the master-pack from Github and use summernote-bs4.js and summernote-bs4.css

Comment: @Gabor Same error after adding this two files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error because of post validation.

I have just add `[ValidateInput(false)]` and its resolve my error.

When we use the Html.Editor than we need to set validation input as `False`